# How to make a button, when pressed the button will disappear and bring up a new div

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me how to make a button, when pressed the button will disappear and bring up a new div,
I'm still a beginner and don't really understand JavaScript, and I haven't made the button yet,
I use bootstrap:

[From This]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyQj8.png

[To this]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpZ28.png

```
<div class="ctg-type">
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Pakaian Wanita</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Atasan</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Outwear</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Dress</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Jumpsuit & Overall</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Batik & Kebaya</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you want to expand div with values on click?

Comment: Can you be more clear please ?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya like this https://youtu.be/ZwC6j-MExlc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something similar to this?

Click on link-button "show more".

```js
$('.show_more').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.ctg-type-link.hide').removeClass('hide');
  $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.ctg-type {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.show_more {
  color: green;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctg-type">
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Pakaian Wanita</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Atasan</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Outwear</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Dress</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Jumpsuit & Overall</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link" href="">Batik & Kebaya</a>
    <a href="" class="show_more">show more</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link hide" href="">Pakaian Wanita2</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link hide" href="">Atasan2</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link hide" href="">Outwear2</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link hide" href="">Dress2</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link hide" href="">Jumpsuit & Overall2</a>
    <a class="ctg-type-link hide" href="">Batik & Kebaya2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript function use to hide button by click on that button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("button").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, It will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help dude the problem is solved now :)